# SSRS 2008 Dynamic Sharepoint Query <ListName> from report parameter

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We are reporting against a SharePoint List that is replicated in more than 10 subsites, and would like to have the SharePoint Query element for the ListName be dynamic.  Reason is, we want a single report to be used for all 10 subsites since each subsite the same list...just different data.

We would like to be able to pass the list name in the query string as a parameter so the report can be dynamic, and we won't have to have 10 exact copies of the same report.  We've already figured out the subsite dynamic part which resides in the datasource portion, and that's working...it's just down to the SharePoint Query XML and the  element where we need to insert the parameter.

We have tried the following 4 ideas with our parameter @List, but we get a "List Not Found" error when trying to view the report for each scenario:

1. List [@]

   ...
2. List {@}/ListName>

   ...
3. @List

   ...
4. =Parameters!List.Value

   ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your query string as an expression like this:

```
="<xml.... " + Parameters!List.Value + "... /xml>"
```

Make sure you click the expression button first (fx).